# What's going on with Java's Date class? Is this a known bug?

Tags: java, date

I know `Date` is mostly deprecated, but I still use it form time to time (less code than using `Calendar`). I came across a truly bizarre bug, and I'm wondering if anyone can explain this to me.

This code, which adds 24 days to the current time:

```
long nowL = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date now = new Date(nowL);
System.out.println("now = "+now);
Date future = new Date(nowL+ 24*24*60*60*1000);
System.out.println("future = "+future);
```

gives this correct output:

> now = Thu Jun 11 10:50:09 IDT 2009
>
> future = Sun Jul 05 10:50:09 IDT 2009

while this code, which adds 25 days:

```
long nowL = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date now = new Date(nowL);
System.out.println("now = "+now);
Date future = new Date(nowL+ 25*24*60*60*1000);
System.out.println("future = "+future);
```

gives this output:

> now = Thu Jun 11 10:51:25 IDT 2009
>
> future = Sun May 17 17:48:37 IDT 2009

I can understand a difference of hours, even days, but can anyone explain why adding too many milliseconds causes going *back in time*?? I'm baffled.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

25*24*60*60*1000 = 2160000000 = 0x80BEFC00

you are computing an integer value, and get an overflow. if it was

25*24*60*60*1000L

everything should be fine.

Comment: Yep, I had the same thought and verified it just to find that you'd already figured it out. :)

Comment: TRWTF is that the compiler doesn't warn you about an integer overflow for a constant..

Comment: well I'll be damned... I was sure I used long.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a bug in the Date class, it's a case of integer overflow. `int`s in Java can only be between -2<sup>31</sup> and 2<sup>31</sup> - 1, but 25 × 24 × 60 × 60 × 1000 is greater than 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 so it overflows.

If you run

```
System.out.println(24*24*60*60*1000);
System.out.println(25*24*60*60*1000);
```

you get the results

```
2073600000
-2134967296
```

If you specify one of the numbers you're multiplying together as a `long` by adding the `L` suffix to it, the product will also be a `long`.  `long` values can go up to 2<sup>63</sup> - 1 so you won't get overflow unless you're adding a *lot* of days to your `Date`s.  For example,

```
System.out.println(25L*24*60*60*1000);
```

gives you

```
2160000000
```